# Write if condition in shell script and run command based on ubuntu version

Tags: shell, ubuntu, sh

Suppose for Ubuntu version 18 or less than that, i want to run command A else command B
How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get version form lsb_release command and then check if major version is less or equal `-le` to 18. If `lsb_release` is not avaiable in a system then just `cat /etc/os-release` and grep from it what is needed.

```
#!/bin/bash

OS_VER=$(lsb_release -sr | cut -d'.' -f1)

if [[ $OS_VER -le 18 ]]; then
    echo "command 1"
else
    echo "command 2"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the version of OS from any of these two file:

- /etc/lsb_release
- /etc/os-release

Then have an if/else command accordingly to check the version.